# How to differentiate each submit button in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

My code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    if($result = $db->query ("SELECT * from countries")) {
        if($count = $result->num_rows) {
            $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
    }
?>
    <div class="region">
        <h1>Europe</h1>

            <ul class="country" style ="list-style-type:none">
                <?php foreach ($rows as $key => $row) { ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""=<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>">
                        <a href=""=<?php echo $row['region_id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></a> <br>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_FILES['country_img']) === true) {
                            if (empty($_FILES['country_img']['name']) === true) {
                                echo 'please choose a file!';   
                                print_r ($_POST);
                                } else {

                                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                                $file_name = $_FILES['country_img']['name'];
                                $file_extn = end(explode('.', $file_name));
                                $file_temp = $_FILES['country_img']['tmp_name'];
                                if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) ===true) {
                                    if ($_POST['id'] = $_POST['id']) {
                                    addcountryimage($row['country_id'], $file_temp, $file_extn);
                                    }
                                    header ('Location: tes2.php');
                                    break;
                                    }else {
                                        echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                                        echo implode (', ', $allowed);
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                            if (empty($row['country_img'] === false)) {
                                echo '<img src="', $row['country_img'], '" alt="', $row['country_name'], '\'s Image">';
                            }                           
                        ?>
                        <p> <?php echo $row['country_bio']; ?></p>
                        <?php
                            global $session_user_id;
                            if (is_admin($session_user_id) === true) { ?>
                            <form action="" method="POST" name="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="hidden_id">
                                <input type="file" name="country_img"> <input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_id').value=$row['country_id']" />
                            </form>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <p> <a href="#">Tour to <?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></a></p>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>               
            <h3> <a href="#">More European Country </a></h3>                
    </div>
```

Everything above works, except the fact that it can't differentiate between each submit button.  For example, when I update the image on the 5th forms it will always update the 1st form. How can I do this?

Comment: try to split between php logic and view logic mixing it together makes it very hard to understood and maintain

Comment: @KrismaHero show the  part of the result html containing forms

Comment: i try to echo the value of the hidden id. it stays the same after each loop. it seems that hidden field value cant be change. only javascript can make it dynamic for each loop. but i cant find a way to do that.

Comment: Have  you a variable which is unique in every loop?

Comment: country_id's are unique on every loop.

Comment: Than use it <input type="hidden" name="id" id="country_id">  getElementById('country_id')

Answer (score 0):

The origin of your issue is using multiple `id` attributes with the same value in your JavaScript events, this is regarded wrong, every element id must be unique, beside this, onclick event with submit typed inputs of form is not working properly.

Add an incremental counter to your loop and then use to distinguish each form hidden element id.

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $key => $row) { ?>
....
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="hidden_id_<?php echo $i;?>">
....
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_id_<?php echo $i;?>').value=$row['country_id']" />
<?php 
 $i++;
} ?>
```

Another note, I think that `onclick` event does not works fine with submit type inputs, so I suggest  to replace it with `onsubmit` event in the form itself as:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="document.getElementById('hidden_id_<?php echo $i;?>').value=$row['country_id']">
```

Comment: your codes are make sense. it really is. but i dont know why, when i print_r the post array it doesnt return anything. back to square none. :(

Comment: @KrismaHero `print_r` for what?

Comment: to check whether it print out all right. debugging.